# error showing integer value in gridview template field

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview column like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:UserProfile, C_Updated %>" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" SortExpression="Updated">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="UpdatedLiteral" runat="server" 
         Text='<%# (Eval("Updated").ToString()) == "0" ? string.Format("<span class=greenText>{0}</span>", GetGlobalResourceObject("Vacancies", "VacancyToday")) : ((int)Eval("Updated")) %>' />

        <asp:Literal ID="UpdateddaysLiteral" runat="server" Text='<%$ Resources:UserProfile, C_UpdatedDays %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

value in updated field is number 0 or greater than 0. but I am getting the error:

> CS0173: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because
>   there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'int'.

Also, I want to show UpdateddaysLiteral only if updated column has value greater than 0. Please suggest how to do this ?

Comment: You are getting this error as on one side of condition you got string and your else is converted to int.

Answer (score 1):

There should be exactly one implicit conversion between  b & c in:

```
var value = a?b:c
```

This conversion can be in any direction.

What this means is that either `b` should be implicitly convertible to `c` or the reverse.

In your case you have `b` as String and `c` as Int and there is NO implicit conversion between the two. That's why this error shows up. [MSDN may help.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb47kt2f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

For example, This will also show the same error:

```
lbldate.Text= (DateTime.Parse(TextBoxActualEndDate.Text)) : null;
```

So the correction is :( Making any one side convertible to other)

```
lbldate.Text= (DateTime?)(DateTime.Parse(TextBoxActualEndDate.Text)) : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last part of your condition:

```
: ((int)Eval("Updated"))
```

Why are you casting "Updated" back to int? Just `Eval("Updated").ToString()` should suffice.

Second part of your question:

```
<asp:Literal ID="UpdateddaysLiteral" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("Updated") > 0 ? "true", "false" %>' ...
```

Comment: I used <asp:Literal ID="UpdateddaysLiteral" runat="server" Text='<%$ Resources:UserProfile, C_UpdatedDays %>' Visible='<%# (Eval("Updated").ToString()) == "0" ? "false": "true" %>' /> as second part but i am getting CS0030: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Comment: `? false: true` boolean values should do instead of quoted strings.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: KISS Principle, that means Keep It Simple Silly. 
Why are you making things complicated in your aspx, when you can do it from code behind flawlessly.

Create a method to do your comparison logic on your codebehind. Something like this.

```
/// This might not be you exact logic, but it will help you 
public string comparevalues(string value)
{
  if(Convert.ToInt32(value)>0)
  {
      //do something
  }
  else
  {
     // do something else;
  }
  return result_as_string;
}
```

In your aspx:

```
<asp:Literal ID="UpdatedLiteral" runat="server"
Text='<%#comparevalues(Eval("Value_To_Evaluate").ToString() %>' />
```